# Correct way to change core module code

Tags: module, contact-us, contact-form

I have one line of code in a core module (contact) in which I need to change.
What is the correct way to make the change to change/overwrite this file?

Comment: it depends on what type of file you want to modify XML PHP JS?

Comment: A php file, in this case post.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do that:

1. You can use composer patches to change file (https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches)
2. Use around plugin to override specific public method on a class. (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html)

Comment: the plugin option should have the higher prio if possible

Answer (score 0):

You can override using magento plugin concept or simply override concept using preferences